# Cisco APIC command equivalent to Cisco IOS `show terminal | include Length`

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios

Whenever I run `show running-config leaf/spine` from APIC, I notice that there is a pause which is `--More--` at the end of the first page.

What I'm trying to achieve is to disable that so that I can save the config to .txt file.

For example, in Cisco IOS we can always do `terminal length 0` to achieve the same. Is there any similar command in Cisco APIC?

I also would like to view the Length setting in the APIC's terminal. In IOS the command is `show terminal | include Length`

Comment: This might sound weird, but do you actually write `terminal`, the full word when using the command? The reason i ask is, that there's a bug on some of the software, where you have to spell it out fully.

Comment: @user56700, of course not. LOL. `ter len 0` will do instead of `terminal length 0`

Comment: Well, if not, then that is your problem. You have to write the full command `terminal length 0` for it to work. :-)

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Comment: @RonMaupin, sorry haven't touched ACI for a while now. Will check again when I have a chance to do that

Answer (score 7):

You have encounter a software bug: **CSCva24843**

Below is a copy/paste from Cisco Bug Search:

ACI | Shorthand for "terminal length 0" does not work

**CSCva24843**

---

**Symptom:**
User enters "term len 0" to disable paging in ACI but still has paging enabled when running a command with large output.

**Conditions:**
User does not spell out "terminal" completely.

**Workaround:**
User must spell out "terminal" completely (e.g. "terminal len 0").

**Further Problem Description:** None.

---

Last Modified:

Feb 11,2018

Status:

Fixed

Severity:

4 Minor

Product:    (1)

Cisco Application Policy Infrastructure Controller (APIC)

Support Cases:
1

---

The command is exactly the same as all other Cisco equipment, this is copy/paste from the complete APIC-EM command line:

---

**terminal**

terminal length

Description: Enable or disable pager for command output

Syntax:

length

Terminal length keyword

NUMBER

Terminal pager length (0=Disable pager). Number range from=0 to=511

Command Mode: exec : Exec Mode

Command Path:

```
# terminal length <NUMBER>
```

Cisco bug: https://bst.cloudapps.cisco.com/bugsearch/bug/CSCva24843/?rfs=iqvred

Complete APIC-EM command line: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/aci/apic/sw/3-x/cli/nx/cr301/b_APIC_NXOS_CLI_Cmd_Reference_301/b_APIC_NXOS_CLI_Cmd_Reference_301_chapter_010100.html#wp2407208257

Comment: Thanks ... what about "Cisco APIC command equivalent to Cisco IOS `show terminal | include Length`"?